# How to use capture on antd upload?

Tags: mobile, file-upload, browser, antd

I'm using antd for upload file, i'm trying to add `capture="environment"` like this code `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="filesystem">` to my code. The code is for open camera only when they access in mobile. How can i implement it in antd Upload ? Here is my code

```
                  <Upload
                    name="avatar"
                    listType="picture-card"
                    className="avatar-uploader"
                    showUploadList={false}
                    accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg"
                  >
```

Answer (score 0):

Antd Upload looks like it would pass on the capture prop to rc-upload (https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/dc4d85583fe6b12c5a3d8b1a1c9de0589752fc3e/components/upload/Upload.tsx#L380), but rc-upload (which antd relies on here) only just recently added support for that. https://github.com/react-component/upload/pull/303

AntD will need to update dependency, but looks like they already have done that in `master`, So maybe wait a bit and update to latest antD, Otherwise fork the component and include the updated dependency in your own package.json.

```
<Upload
    name="avatar"
    listType="picture-card"
    className="avatar-uploader"
    showUploadList={false}
    accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg"
    capture="environment"
>
```